# How to call methods from object classes in appdelegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have 2 object classes. Class A and Class B.
In my appdelegate.m, I can access my methods in class A but not class B. I don't know why.

In appdelegate.m

....
....
....

```
-(void)classAMethod:(classA *)classAObj {

     [classAObj classAMethod];
}

-(void)classBMethod:(classB *)classBObj {

     [classBObj classBMethod];
}
```

....
....
....

In my VC class, I typed this codes:

....
....
....

```
myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate classAMethod:classAObj];

[appDelegate classBMethod:classBObj];
```

....
....
....

It only able to access method in class A. How do I access method in class B? Can anyone help? Thanks.
*If it's not elaborate well, do tell me again.

Comment: [appDelegate classAMethod:classAObj];

[appDelegate classBMethod:classAObj];  //here you need to pass the classBObject

Comment: Check if you have declared the classBMethod in class B interface.

Comment: What happens? Do you get a crash, a compiler error, or what? Is this actually real code?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `classA` obj instead of `classB` obj in the following line.

```
[appDelegate classBMethod:classAObj];
```

Please check that.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are miss-using the language. take a look at "classAMethod", you declare it at appDelegate.m, thus it belongs to appDelegate class. In classAMethod body you call the method (recursive call) on the object classAObj  which doesn't implement this method. You actually sending the object classAObj   a message it unable to respond to. In any case you have a really messy code...

Comment: My intention is to have two object classes with it own specific methods and purpose. Cause I want it to cater for reuse these classes in the future. Any idea I can do it better?

Answer (score 0):

```
[appDelegate classAMethod:classAObj];

[appDelegate classBMethod:classAObj];  //here you need to pass the classBObject
```

Comment: That's my typo, sorry about it. I changed it to classBObject but still it couldn't access the method in class B.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of involving the app delegate? All you appear to be doing is calling the same method on the object you are passing in. Why not just do:

```
[classAObj classAmethod];
```

Directly in your view controller? It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve.